# Getting the error: can't convert expression to float

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am new to python and I am trying to find  [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) of a Riemannian metric on a surface but I got this error: **TypeError: can't convert expression to float**. For simplicity, I wrote another code with exactly the same error (**my fundamental code is very long and not readable so I tried this example code to understand my fault**). Here is my example code:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

coor = symbols('x y')

x = [coor[0] ** 2, coor[1]]


christoffels = np.zeros((2,2))

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        christoffels[i][j] = x[i] * x[j]


print(christoffels)
```

Could you please tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: You need to provide us with the full stack of the error. More importantly, the line at which it appears.

Comment: Please copy paste the entire error stack trace and the exception

Comment: As a general rule using `numpy` and `sympy` together is hard to do right.  `sympy.lambdify` can be used to convert `sympy` expressions into `numpy` functions.  If `sympy` objects are put in `numpy` arrays the result is an object dtype array, not a fast numeric one.  It's best to stick with one or the other - at least until you become proficient in both.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for advice.

Comment: @hpaulj What about lists? They won't cause problems with sympy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the assignment:

```
christoffels[i][j] = x[i] * x[j]
```

On the right-hand, we have `symbols` and on the left-hand, there is NumPy floats array cell.

Therefore Python had difficulties to convert the `symbols` to a float.

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Let's fix it by defining the matrix as [`sympy` matrix](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html):

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

coor = symbols('x y')

x = [coor[0] ** 2, coor[1]]


# Create sympy array
christoffels = zeros(2,2)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        # Now assignment works
        # NOTE: In sympy location denoted as [i, j] and not [i][j]
        christoffels[i, j] = x[i] * x[j]

# Matrix([[x**4, x**2*y], [x**2*y, y**2]])
print(christoffels)
```

Comment: Dear Aviv, Thank you for your nice and clear answer. I have a question. We are always required to use only sympy or numpy in a line of a code? Or, we can use them together? I mean the error was occurring  because of using sympy features accompanied with the numpy features, we must to care about this rule?

Comment: @SikSik welcome :) It just like "string"s and "int"s; we can use them together in code, but we have to be careful on how we use them together and how we act operations on them.

Answer (score 2):

In an `isympy` session (where `x`, `y` are already defined)

```
In [1]: coor = symbols('x y')

In [2]: coor
Out[2]: (x, y)
```

`coor` is a tuple

```
In [3]: xx = [coor[0]**2, coor[1]]

In [4]: xx
Out[4]: 
⎡ 2   ⎤
⎣x , y⎦
```

`xx` is a list containing 2 sympy objects.

If we make an object dtype array, we can assign sympy elements:

```
In [5]: xy = np.empty((2,2),object)

In [6]: for i in range(2):
   ...:     for j in range(2):
   ...:         xy[i,j] = xx[i]*xx[j]
   ...: 

In [7]: xy
Out[7]: 
array([[x**4, x**2*y],
       [x**2*y, y**2]], dtype=object)
```

Or a list comprehension way of creating the same

```
In [8]: [[i*j for j in xx] for i in xx]
Out[8]: 
⎡⎡ 4   2  ⎤  ⎡ 2     2⎤⎤
⎣⎣x , x ⋅y⎦, ⎣x ⋅y, y ⎦⎦
```

As nested list and then array as before:

```
In [9]: np.array(_)
Out[9]: 
array([[x**4, x**2*y],
       [x**2*y, y**2]], dtype=object)
```

Object dtype arrays come up often on SO questions, but usually when creating 'ragged' arrays.  They don't have the speed or computing power of numeric dtype arrays.

Some basic math does work with object dtype arrays, as long as the elements themselves implement the right methods (such as addition)

```
In [10]: xy.sum(axis=1)
Out[10]: array([x**4 + x**2*y, x**2*y + y**2], dtype=object)

In [11]: np.exp(xy)
...
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Pow which has no callable exp method
```

(no one implements a `exp` method.)

`sympy` runs in `python`, so basic python structures like tuples and lists are natural.  The interaction with `numpy` is hit-or-miss, and never as fast as the pure numeric arrays.  `sympy's` own matrix/array imports usually will give you more power, but require more study.

The `sympy.Matrix` object given in the other answer:

```
In [20]: zz = zeros(2,2)

In [21]: for i in range(2):
    ...:     for j in range(2):
    ...:         zz[i,j] = xx[i]*xx[j]
    ...: 

In [22]: zz
Out[22]: 
⎡  4    2  ⎤
⎢ x    x ⋅y⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎢ 2      2 ⎥
⎣x ⋅y   y  ⎦
```

Can also be constructed from the nested list:

```
In [23]: Matrix(Out[8])
Out[23]: 
⎡  4    2  ⎤
⎢ x    x ⋅y⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎢ 2      2 ⎥
⎣x ⋅y   y  ⎦
```